# Keyboard shortcut for moving tabs in SublimeText3

Tags: sublimetext3

Every time I open a new tab in SublimeText I have to take my hands off the keyboard and use the mouse to move the newly opened tab to the desired position among the existing tabs...

Surely there must be a keyboard shortcut for moving SublimeText Tabs left and/or right?

Please say yes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as if there are no shortcuts to do this.

You can see all actions and their shortcuts in the command palette (Ctrl+p on Windows). There is no such action as `Move this tab to the left`.

The good news, however, is that there is a plugin that does exactly this:

https://github.com/SublimeText/MoveTab

You can install it using [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/).

Comment: Hell Yeah!  You just made my day.  :)

Comment: Just FYI, not "*all actions and their shortcuts*" are available in the Command Palette (whose shortcut is Ctrl-Shift-P, not Ctrl-P). Only those commands which have been entered into a suitable `.sublime-commands` file will show up.

Answer (score 4):

Not by default unfortunately, but there are two awesome things about Sublime to be aware of:

- This plugin https://github.com/SublimeText/MoveTab will let you move tabs with CTRL + Shift + page up/down
- You can go to any tab by pressing ctrl+p and typing the name of the tab, so if your tabs are disorganized, you don't have to visually search for them or organize them as long as you know the name of the file you want (or a substring of it if it's unique enough)